# Urn question(probability)

Tags: probability

An urn contains 4 red balls labelled 1, 6 red balls labelled 0, and 6 white balls labelled 1.  How many white balls labelled 0 must be in the urn for the events of a certain colour drawn or acertain label drawn to be independent when a ball is drawn uniformly at random from the urn?

For this question, I think the number of white balls must be equal to the number of red balls, and labelled 0 must be equal to labelled 1. Therefore, 4 white balls labelled 0. Am I right?

Comment: Under the scenario described above, if you drew a ball labeled 1, what is the probability that it red?  What about if you drew a ball labeled 0?  If they are not the same, can you say that there is independence?

Comment: So to satisfy the condition, I have to solve that 4/10 = 6/(6+x)?

Answer (score 1):

Let number of balls that are white and labelled 0 be x. Then

$\mathbb{P}(\text{Color}=\text{Red},\text{Label}=1) = \frac{4}{16+x}$,$\mathbb{P}(\text{Color}=\text{Red},\text{Label}=0) = \frac{6}{16+x}$,$\mathbb{P}(\text{Color}=\text{White},\text{Label}=1) = \frac{6}{16+x}$,$\mathbb{P}(\text{Color}=\text{White},\text{Label}=0) = \frac{x}{16+x}$

From which we deduce $\mathbb{P}(\text{Color}=\text{Red}) = \frac{10}{16+x}$,$\mathbb{P}(\text{Color}=\text{White}) = \frac{6+x}{16+x}$,$\mathbb{P}(\text{Label}=1) = \frac{10}{16+x}$ and $\mathbb{P}(\text{Label}=0) = \frac{6+x}{16+x}$

From independence property $\mathbb{P}(\text{Color}=\text{Red},\text{Label}=1) = \frac{4}{16+x}=\mathbb{P}(\text{Color}=\text{Red})\cdot \mathbb{P}(\text{Label}=1)=\frac{10}{16+x}\cdot\frac{10}{16+x}$ whence $x=9$.

It's straightforward to verify independence in the other three cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you pull a red ball, the ratio of $0:1$ labels is $2:3$. For the events to be independent, this needs to be the case if you pull a white ball, hence $2:3=6:x$, and therefore $x=9$.